# Trying to lookup a value in a data.frame and then return results from object by the same name

Tags: r, class, types

I've searched and searched for information trying to turn my output into a different class of thing, or get() or assign(), but keep striking out.

I have a data.frame that's populated as follows:

```
  card     lookups           drops
1    1       char1       chardrops
2    2       char2       chardrops
3    3       char1       chardrops
4    4       char2       chardrops
5    5         bar        bardrops
6    6         foo        fooDrops
7    7         foo        fooDrops
```

I then grab a value from the lookups column within the data.frame with

`lookup <- cardsTable$lookups[1]`

and a value from the drops column with

`drops <- cardsTable$drops[1]`

These return:

```
> drops
[1] chardrops
Levels: foodrops bardrops chardrops
> lookup
[1] char1
Levels: foo bar char2 char1
```

I'm trying to get back the objects by the same name (turning around and using these as arguments in `sample()`), so I need to retrieve:

```
> char1
  award prob
1  Erik 0.25
2  Nick 0.25
3   Sam 0.25
4  Mike 0.25
```

and

```
> chardrops
  qty prob
1  10 0.15
2  15 0.30
3  20 0.25
4  25 0.20
5  50 0.10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cardsTable$lookups` is a factor.  You will need to use

```
get(as.character(lookup))
```